# Which is an efficient way for checking values of multiple rows with the same keyvalue in two different excel-files/dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have two excel-files. Both contain information about the same data objects. The data objects are identified by the object number (column `ON`) which is of type `str`.

> example:

```
Table 1                                Table 2
ON      colA  colB  colToUpdate         ON   colImportant
1.2.3    abc   123                      1.2.3      inf
2.9.6    ert   987                      1.2.3      mat
3.5.0    nms   021                      2.9.6      mat
                                        2.9.6      tr
                                        2.9.6      ch
                                        3.5.0      tr
```

and

```
myValues={inf, ch}
```

> Task:

*I need to check if one of the `colImportant` values in table 2 are in my `myValues` and that data object (row with same object number) needs to get the value 'Ok' in `colToUpdate` in `df1`.*

> expectation:

```
new Table 1
   ON      colA  colB  colToUpdate        
   1.2.3    abc   123     Ok                
   2.9.6    ert   987     Ok               
   3.5.0    nms   021     NaN
```

I thought about to save both in a separate dataframe (table1 ind `df1` and table2 in `df2`) and always search for the same object number in `df2` when updating the next column in `df1`. But that would always search the whole `df2` (there are roundabout 30000 data objects, that means 30000 rows in `df1`. In `df2`, there are 75000 rows because one data object can be stored multiple times with another value in `colImportant`, as you can see above).

Another idea is to make a `tempCol` in `df1` where I put all the values from the `colImportant` in `df2` with a separator like `,` (BUT HOW, I need some ***merging of multiple rows into one in `df2` and than merge the dfs by `'ON'`***). Then, when I want to update the rows in `df1` by some criteria, I have to check the splitted values.
Ones finished, I can delete `tempCol`.
That should look like:

```
  Table 1                                
    ON      colA  colB  colToUpdate tempCol       
    1.2.3    abc   123               inf,mat       
    2.9.6    ert   987               mat,tr,ch      
    3.5.0    nms   021               inf
```

Comment: is `ON` on Table 1 unique? is `ON` on Table 2 `str` or `int`? I would first try to remove `.` in Table1.ON and make the two same datatype.

Comment: Yes, `ON` ist unique in Table 1. Both are `str`, and now both are stored with dots (the reason is that I don't want to change df1 much because I will export that one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach:

```
tmp_df = df2.groupby('ON').colImportant.apply(lambda x: 'OK' if (~x.isin(myValues)).any() 
                                                             else np.nan)

df1=df1.merge(tmp_df.reset_index()[['colImportant']], 
               left_on=df1.ON, 
               right_on=tmp_df.index).drop('key_0', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
+----+-------+--------+----------------+
|    | ON    | colA   | colImportant   |
|----+-------+--------+----------------|
|  0 | 1.2.3 | abc    | OK             |
|  1 | 2.9.6 | ert    | OK             |
|  2 | 3.5.0 | nms    | nan            |
+----+-------+--------+----------------+
```

Not perfect, but I think you can sort that out.

Comment: @thestruggleisreal you can't remove `str.replace` since that is used to match `df1.ON` with `df2.ON`.

Comment: it works because I inserted dots in `df2.ON`. I don't want to modify `df1.ON` because that will be used for other processes. Also, doesn't it have to be without the `~` negotiation?

Comment: I think you are correct. Should be without `~`, i.e., if some of the value appears in your `myValues`. But would that mean the 3rrd row be `OK` instead of `NaN`

Comment: Ok sorry I made a mistake in my example. Thank you for your answer !

Comment: To make the answer perfect: the Oks and nans should be written in df1.colToUpdate